# Best approach for dealing with continuous predictors with missing data in random forests

Tags: random-forest, missing-data, continuous-data, data-imputation

I was thinking about a problem I'm facing: I have `wage` data that I want to add to my model, but it's incomplete (data for about 70% of my observations). So, I was thinking about two approaches:

- Turn it into a categorical variable, based on  intervals, and add a "No information" category.
- Keep it as a continuous variable, fill missings with `-100` and add a dummy variable that takes value "1" if there's no information.

Ideally I would like to implement the latter, so I lose less information. My intuition tells me RF might be able to infer between the negative values and the dummy that those observations are different, but I'm not quite sure.

This has arisen several times while developing models, so I'd really appreciate any answers.

Thanks

Comment: why would you like to add observations with "no information"? What would be the benefit of it? Couldn't you just *not add* these records? That would pretty much solve the problem.

Comment: and BTW, the question in the title is a completely different question - it looks like zero-inflated models, but in the question you ask about NAs basically. And also, what does it mean "disproportionate amount"?

Comment: I've edited your title because like @Curious, I found that it did not quite match your actual question. Please check to see that I've captured your meaning correctly.

Comment: @Curious, because data with and without wages come from different sources. If I drop the rows that don't match, my final model will be poor at generallizing for the whole population

Comment: The second approach as you have it doesn't make sense: why would you fill with zeros and create dummy variable, when you can just set it to `NA`? And then again, you can just drop these records from the model since it will do nothing. I just looks like some issue of data organization more than modelling....

Comment: What you're telling me is like telling me that if I was training a model to predict if an animal is a rat, a cat or a dog I should drop all rat records because in one of my variables I have no data for rats. I won't do that.

Comment: In approach 2, you can even skip the dummy variable part. The trees will split on the imputed variable multiple times if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelM! Seems intuitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second approach is a good one assuming that there are no true zeroes in the data. What matters is to give the missing values a number more extreme than exists in the dataset; whether that is zero, negative, or positive, all that matters is that it falls outside the data range.

(Edit: Actually, you can even skip the dummy variable here, it's not actually contributing additional information.

The first approach is inferior in that it needlessly bins the data and thereby throws away potentially useful information.

A third option is imputation (h/t to rolando2 for the suggestion), which some implementations of random forests can do for you automatically. How useful this is will partly depend on how well `wage` can be predicted by the other variables in your dataset.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. So if I impute that data to`-100` (There's actually some zero-wage observations), the trees should consistently notice that this continuous variable is non-linear by nature

Comment: @JuanC Yes, that's correct. Nonlinearity is not a problem, so -100 will work well in your case.

Comment: Many of the popular implementations of RF can treat missing values separately, making a split like "Xi>a or missing" vs "Xi<=a". That'd be a little more efficient.

Comment: Why would "more extreme" be more desirable than a modern imputation method such as multiple imputation?

Comment: @rolando2 You're right, it's entirely possible that multiple imputation would be a better option. I've edited the answer to add that.

Answer (score 1):

What about imputing the missing values? There are various strategies: mean, random values, train a model to predict the missing values, ... In case this is a suitable option for your use case, I recommend reading this [scikit-learn documentation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) about the imputation of missing values.

Comment: I find this a welcome answer and I'm sure people would benefit if you would elaborate on it.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is possible if you scale/normalize your data before passing it to your model. If you scale your data to be between say 0-1, then you could fill missing values with something like -1. This would allow you to avoid adding another column, but should probably only be done if you are also normalizing all of your other continuous features.

Comment: Scaling/normalization achieves nothing here that would not be achieved by just setting missing values to -1

Comment: If -1 is a common wage in the dataset, the missing values would be confused with actual values of -1. By scaling it, you can ensure that whatever value you choose for the missing values is not mistaken for a true value. This may not be the case for this particular problem, but can be applied to other problems with a larger range of possible values.

Comment: 1) It's a pretty strange job if you're *paying* to work there, which is what I guess a wage of -1 would imply, and 2) again, scaling/normalization is unnecessary - all that matters is that the value should be more extreme than any present in the dataset.